# Cell variable inside COUNTIF

Tags: variables, google-sheets, countif

I have a column with many words in each cell. I want to count how many times a word is in the column and use:

```
=COUNTIF(Data!C3:C9,"*word*")
```

It works fine, now I want to reference a cell instead put the word. I am trying this, but it doesn't work:

```
=COUNTIF(Data!C3:C9,"*"+A3+"*")
```

How can I use the cell variable inside the criterion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Spreadsheet, to concatenate two or more strings use ampersand, that is: "&"
Try the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF(Data!C3:C9,"*"&A3&"*")
```

Or you can alternatively try:

```
=COUNTIF(Data!C3:C9,CONCATENATE("*",A3,"*"))
```